# Upgrade Jaunty Jackalope

Tags: upgrade, release

I've an outdated jaunty installation on one of my server boxes...

trying to do a do-release-upgrade returns a

```
An upgrade from 'jaunty' to 'lucid' is not supported with this tool.
```

Is there any way i can upgrade it to karmic and then step-by-step from there to lucid ?

cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the Alternate CD from [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/karmic/) then burn it or mount it using

`sudo mount -o loop <the_iso_name> /media`

then run this by terminal or by pressing `Alt+f2`
for gnome:

`gksu "sh /media/cdromupgrade"`

or for kde:

`kdesudo "sh /media/cdromupgrade"`

this will upgrade your system to karmic.

Comment: Hey, yes, thank you, I just stumbled upon the "upgrading using alternate CD" section in the karmic upgrade guide and did as you've written :) thanks a lot!

one thing to notice is that you have to deny internet access during the cdromupgrade - else it would fail with the same error message i reportet in miy first question :)

Answer (score 0):

Without downloading the Alternate CD, it is still possible to upgrade, with a small tweak. The [page you're mentioning in the comment](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades/Jaunty) has been updated to reflect this.

More details can be found in [another answer regarding the Jaunty upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/a/135028/3004).